# JAXB xmlelement default value for boolean flag

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jersey, jetty

I have a `JAXB` class as shown below which is used as a parameter in
`POST` method . Its having a parameter called isTrue which is an
optional parameter,the default value of the parameter should be true
when its not passed in the `REST` request. But when i am trying to
invoke the method and not passing it the default value of set as
`false`. can anyone suggest me what could be the cause of the issue?i
need `true` as the value when i am not passing any value for `isTrue`.
I am using REST webservices using jersey.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "param")
public class Param {
     private boolean isTrue;

     @XmlElement(required = false, name = "isTrue", defaultValue = "true")
     public boolean isTrue() {
        return isTrue;
     }

     public void setTrue(boolean isTrue) {
        this.isTrue = isTrue;
     }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a known issue, refer to https://java.net/projects/jaxb2-commons/pages/Default-Value

Basically the article above describes a JAXB plugin that explicitly initializes default boolean variables to true, if desired.  Since you are not generating JAXB code and writing it manually, you can just explicitly initialize the parameter to true:

```
private boolean isTrue = true;
```

This is what the plugin referenced above does as a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I think its not allowed to do that.As we are specifying defaultValue = "true" in the @XmlElement it should be able to take true as the parameter right?Can you please tell me what I am missing here?

Comment: Agreed, I would have expected what you had to work. Have you tried using field accessor type? I will update my answer with an example.

Comment: This is actually a known problem, see here for background https://java.net/projects/jaxb2-commons/pages/Default-Value The solution presented there is to explicitly set the value to true as in my first answer. The url I gave does this via a plugin but you can do it manually since you are writing the code yourself.